# Can you tell me why this generates time limit exceeded in spoj(Prime Number Generator)

Tags: c++, generator, primes

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
#include<math.h>
using namespace std;    

bool prime[1000000500];
void generate(long long end)
{
    memset(prime,true,sizeof(prime));
    prime[0]=false;
    prime[1]=false;

        for(long long i=0;i<=sqrt(end);i++)
        {
         if(prime[i]==true)
         {
             for(long long y=i*i;y<=end;y+=i)
             {
                 prime[y]=false;
             }
         }
        }
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    long long b,e;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while(n--)
    {
        cin>>b>>e;
        generate(e);
        for(int i=b;i<e;i++)
        {
            if(prime[i])
                printf("%d\n",i);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

That's my code for spoj prime generator.
Altought it generates the same output as another accepted code ..

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to sieve every number up to the end number. That's just silly. Only operate on the range between beginning and end numbers. (A partial sieve)

I've solved this problem in Python and that was the way I finally managed to do it. I also started by calculating all of the primes up to the square root of the potential maximum, 1000000000. This is only 31623 so it doesn't take long.

From this list use those numbers up to the square root of the current case maximum to sieve the current case.

Answer (score 2):

This problem requires a Segmented Sieve implementation. A simple segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes can be easily programmed in C/C++ in about 50-60 lines of code.
If you implement a segmented sieve, you need to only allocate memory for the maximum sized segment mentioned in the problem.

There are a couple of other optimizations that can help a bit. I will list the ones I did in my solution:

- Check for multiples of only prime numbers up to the square root of the maximum number.
- A lookup array of all prime numbers till the square root of the maximum possible number i.e sqrt(10^9) can be pre-calculated and added to the source code. SPOJ source code size limit is 50000 bytes for this problem and adding this lookup array still fits within this size limit.
- While crossing out multiples, start from y=i*i, but check only odd multiples    of i.

With these optimizations my code in C++ ran in about 0.05s. Even without these
optimizations I think a segmented sieve should get accepted. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

An easy trick to make it faster is to lift out `sqrt` from the for loop:

```
double sqrtOfEnd = sqrt(end);
for(long long i=0; i<=sqrtOfEnd; i++)
{
  ...
```

You don't need to recalculate the square root on every loop.
As pointed out by others this might not be enough and you might have to concider other methods of finding primes.

Answer (score 1):

Since you need to output primes from a number of sequences, may-be keep around the results from previous sievings and only continue to fill in the rest of the table as needed?

Comment: That's a lot of numbers to store. Calculating the primes isn't a problem, but storing them might be.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it faster - for test cases such as the range 999900000-1000000000, Eratosthene's sieve algorithm is too slow. There are other alternatives you could try and will yield better results.

PS. Of course I won't tell you which these are. Do your homework. :P

Comment: Well i didn't post thsi question until i am so desperate about it ... so if you know how i can optimize it ? Please tell.

Comment: There are a number of primality tests that can be adapted for your purpose (see Miller-Rabin, Agrawal & Biswas, Bernstein in "Proving primality in essentially quartic random time") as well as other approaches in prime number generation (Sieve of Atkin). I'm sure there are others as well, as it's a relatively 'hot' research topic.

Comment: Eratosthene's sieve algorithm is not too slow. A modified version that operates only on the test range and not on the entire range from 0 to 1000000000 will do fine.

Comment: @nakedfanatic: You mean, a segmented Eratosthene's sieve is not too slow. It's not the same with the traditional sieve algorithm, and it certainly isn't as easy to implement. I was going to avoid mentioning it, but w/e. :)

Comment: True, I leaned heavily on Python's extended slice notation. I expect it would be more painful to implement in C++.

Comment: not a "segmented" sieve. Segmented sieve proceeds by segments, one after another; here we just need one initial sieve up to 32000 and then just sieve each segment as requested, in isolation. And SoE is fast enough, just might need to make a variant that works on odds only, for twice the speed (work with half-length array, where `i`s entry stands for a number `start_offset + 2*i`).

Answer (score 0):

@nakedfantaic
Exactly!

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <cmath>

unsigned int numbers[3500], len;

inline bool prime(unsigned int x)
{
    unsigned int i, last = sqrt(x);
    for (i = 2; i <= last; i++) {
        if (!(x % i)) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

void generate()
{
    for (unsigned int i = 2; i < 32000; i++) {
        if (prime(i)) {
            numbers[len++] = i;
        }
    }
}

inline bool process(unsigned long x)
{
    unsigned int i, last = sqrt(x);
    for (i = 0; i < len && numbers[i] <= last; i++) {
        if (!(x % numbers[i])) {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int tests;
    unsigned long begin, end;
    generate();
    scanf("%d", &tests);
    while (tests-- > 0) {
        scanf("%u %u", &begin, &end);
        if (begin == 1) {
            begin++;
        }
        while (begin <= end) {
            if (process(begin)) {
                printf("%u\n", begin);
            }
            begin++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

http://pastebin.com/G5ZRd5vH

Comment: this is trial division; it is much much slower than the sieve of Eratosthenes which @nakedfanatic proposed.

Answer (score 0):

I can help with python 3.4 and my working code for spoj(prime generator) is like this:

```
import math
primes = [True for i in range(int(math.sqrt(1000000000))+1)]
tes = int(math.sqrt(math.sqrt(1000000000)*2))+1
for i in range(2,tes):
    if primes[i]:
        for z in range(i*i,int(math.sqrt(1000000000))+1,i):
            primes[z] = False
for z in range(int(input().strip())):
    m,n = map(int,input().strip().split())
    if n == 1:
        print('')
        continue
    elif m == 1:
        m += 1
    ans = [True for i in range(n-m+1)]
    for i in range(2,int(math.sqrt(1000000000))+1):
        if primes[i]:
            if i > n:
                break
            num = m//i
            if num*i != m:
                num += 1
            if num < 2:
                num = 2
            while num*i <= n:
                ans[num*i-m] = False
                num += 1
    for i in range(n-m+1):
        if ans[i]:
            print(i+m)
    print('')
```